# Getting permanent residence in Germany under Beschv paragraph 4 Managers and Specialists

Tags: germany, resident-permit, residence-cards

I've got a national visa to Germany under Beschv 4 Managers and Specialists instead of the visa for Blue Card which I've applied for. 
Am struggling now with two questions:
1) can I get standard Blue Card based on this visa ?
2) If not, what will be the difference in terms of a period required to stay in Germany to get a permanent residence ? Would it be a status which could allow me to work in other German and EU companies ? Could I bring my wife in Germany without a need for her to pass A1 exam in German ?
Thank you in advance.

EDIT based on comments:

Thank you for clarification. The reason I've got paragraph 4 was actually a mismatch between my master diploma, stating I'm a physics engineer, while position in German company is called solution architect. So they said it doesn't match exactly. Salary is 80K+, so it's not an issue in this case.

So most probably I wouldn't be able to turn my current beschv 4 visa into Blue Card upon arrival, right ?

Comment: Hi Yaroslav, I am facing the same situation at the moment. Can you, please, update your question if you have any new info after the time passed? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have to guess why you haven't got the Blue Card. Most likely because the lower income limit is not met. The BeschV §4 is an alternative without an income limit, but then, *you may be approved* by the employment agency and subsequently get a residence permit. Blue card holders are automatically qualified. That's the difference.

So, no, you cannot upgrade this to a Blue Card. You could apply for it on its rules, of course.

Your wife does not need to pass the A1 exam if your and your wive's residence in Germany is **temporary**. That's the general guideline. Choose your poison.

Comment: Are a spouse's language requirements different if the principal has a blue card as opposed to a BeschV §4 visa?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.